# TextInfo.ToTitleCase does not work as expected for ALL CAPS strings

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I was trying to use `TextInfo.ToTitleCase` to convert some names to proper case. it works fine for strings in lowercase and mixed case but for strings with all characters in upper case, it returns the input string as is.
Nothing about this behavior is mentioned in MSDN documentation, any insights?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx) docs:

> Remarks
>   Generally, title casing converts the first character of a word to uppercase and the rest of the characters to lowercase. However, **this method does not currently provide proper casing to convert a word that is entirely uppercase, such as an acronym**. The following table shows the way the method renders several strings.

so it's expected behaviour. You could lowercase your string first if it's all uppercase, then run ToTitleCase on it.

Comment: @Nims -- In your belated defense, the [current] docs don't say that ToTitleCase won't do squat to all caps. My first impression was that it'd *not ignore* all caps and would title case anyhow. Whoops. `textInfo.ToTitleCase(strAllCaps.ToLower())` it is.

Comment: The current documentation also says "We reserve the right to make this API slower in the future." Got to love Microsoft! (:

Answer (score 11):

I suspect it's because words in all capitals are expected to be abbreviations such as USA.

For example, you wouldn't expect "Earthquake hits USA" to be changed to "Earthquake Hits Usa" would you?

Comment: That is a bug then. Unicode specifies "USA" -> "Usa". Edit: OK, not a bug, as it is mentioned in the docs, but surprising behavior.

Answer (score 7):

The MSDN documentation says:

Generally, title casing converts the first character of a word to uppercase and the rest of the characters to lowercase. However, a word that is entirely uppercase, such as an acronym, is not converted.

So it works as intended. Try `TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextInfo.ToLowerCase("STRINGINCAPS"))`

like:

```
string TitleCaseString;
TextInfo myTI = new CultureInfo("en-US",false).TextInfo;
TitleCaseString = myTI.ToTitleCase(myTI.ToLowerCase("STRINGINCAPS"));
```

Comment: I should add the wording changed at .net 3.5, and isn't as clear about this fact.